# Need advise on logic for pulling audience who did not open email X days

Tags: marketing-cloud, query, dataextensions, data-views

I am trying to find out audience who did not open email for last 5 months.

What should be the correct approach in finding the audience?

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
s.SubscriberID
, s.SubscriberKey
, sub.EmailAddress
, s.EventDate
, s.AccountID
, s.JobID 
FROM _Sent s WITH (NOLOCK) 
LEFT JOIN _Subscribers sub ON s.SubscriberKey = sub.SubscriberKey 
WHERE s.SubscriberID IN (
  SELECT DISTINCT 
  SubscriberID 
  FROM _open 
  WHERE 
  DATEDIFF(day,EventDate,GETDATE()) >= 180
) 
AND s.SubscriberID IN (
    SELECT DISTINCT 
    SubscriberID 
    FROM _click 
    WHERE DATEDIFF(day,EventDate,GETDATE()) >= 152
) 
AND s.AccountID = 'XXXXXX'
```

OR

Just this?

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
 s.SubscriberID
, s.SubscriberKey
, sub.EmailAddress
, s.EventDate
, s.AccountID
, s.JobID 
FROM _Sent s WITH (NOLOCK) 
LEFT JOIN _Subscribers sub ON s.SubscriberKey = sub.SubscriberKey 
WHERE s.SubscriberID IN (
    SELECT DISTINCT SubscriberID 
    FROM _open 
    WHERE DATEDIFF(day,EventDate,GETDATE()) >= 152
)
```

Comment: You may have to break this up into two queries for performance reasons. It will make it easier for you to code too. Where does your audience live? One data extension? or do you use lists? You shouldn't need the _subscribers data view at all, depending on your setup

Comment: @garek007 Our data lives in 1 master data extension and audience is filtered from that. So yes, 1 data extension includes all audience. So, I think I will have to do some kind of JOIN to get other data like name, country etc. How can i break the query, can you please show an example? Since you mentioned that i won't need subscriber data view so should I do something like this? `SELECT SubscriberKey
FROM AudienceDE
WHERE Email_Sign_UP = YES 
AND SubscriberKey IN
(SELECT SubscriberKey
FROM _open
WHERE DATEDIFF(day,EventDate,GETDATE()) >= 152
)`

Answer (score 0):

Since your data lives in one DE, try this. Add a few more columns to your Data Extension, TotalOpens, UniqueOpens, TotalClicks, UniqueClicks. Then run the following query as an UPDATE and select that data extension.

```
SELECT SubscriberKey, count(SubscriberKey) as UniqueOpens
FROM _Open
WHERE SubscriberKey IN (
    SELECT SubscriberKey
    FROM [YOUR MASTER DATA EXTENSION NAME HERE]
)
AND IsUnique = 1
GROUP BY SubscriberKey
```

If your main data extension has your SubscriberKey column marked as Primary Key, this will update the row your subscriber lives on with the number of unique opens found in the _Open Data view.

Remove AND IsUnique = 1 to get total opens and change _Open to _Click for clicks.

And this is very important, DO NOT FORGET TO SET THIS QUERY AS AN UPDATE or you will lose all the data in your data extension. You may want to make a copy of your data extension just to be safe.

This will give you all of the unique opens by subscriber in the past 6 months.

**UPDATE**
Sorry I missed that you are trying to get people who HAVE NOT opened, so do this.

Create a new Data Extension based on your master (so you don't screw up the master).

Use this query

```
SELECT SubscriberKey
FROM [YOUR MASTER DATA EXTENSION NAME HERE]
WHERE SubscriberKey NOT IN (
    SELECT SubscriberKey
    FROM _Open
)
```

That pulls everyone from your MASTER data extension who DOES NOT appear in the _Open data view. Basically if they are not in the _Open data view it's because they haven't opened an email.

This will pull anyone who isn't in the _Open data view and since it goes back 6 months, it gets people who haven't opened in six months. If you want to limit to a range do this.

```
SELECT SubscriberKey
FROM [YOUR MASTER DATA EXTENSION NAME HERE]
WHERE SubscriberKey NOT IN (
    SELECT SubscriberKey
    FROM _Open
    WHERE EventDate >= DATEADD(mm,DATEDIFF(mm,0,GETDATE())-5,0)
)
```

Comment: Hi @garek007 First of all thank you for your help and time. So, I am trying to create a separate DE with a list of customer who did not open our emails in last 5 months. I am not looking to update the master audience DE.  If I understand your query correctly, it looks like it will give customers who opened emails at least once while I am trying to find customers who exists in our master DE and DID NOT open our email in last 5 months. Any advise?

Comment: Sorry, updated above

Comment: Thanks @garek007 that does makes sense & I see that now i do not have to save data views locally if I am simply looking for not open in last 6months. For second query, i have one question, if I am looking for a range, lets say 5 months (152 days), shouldn't I do `SubscriberKey IN (
    SELECT SubscriberKey
    FROM _Open
    WHERE EventDate >= DATEADD(mm,DATEDIFF(mm,0,GETDATE())-152,0)
)'  AND SECOND CONDITION AS WELL  ' SubscriberKey NOT IN (SELECT SubscriberKey
    FROM _Open
    )' Doing NOT IN will ignore people who did not open email in 5months  because they exists in open data view

Comment: if you want to change it to days, make sure to change mm to dd. It's true that if you want to find people from 5 months ago, to 3 months ago, you'll need a second WHERE clause. Try this out a few times and see what it does for you. You may want to start a new question if you have other needs